# Updating a label in Tkinter on a button press

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a button that when clicked updates the number on a label. What I am trying to accomplish is that when someone scores a goal, you can click the Goal! button and it will update the teams score.

```
import sys
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

class team1:
score = 0

def goal(self):
    self.score += 1
    team1_attempt.set(text = self.score)

team1 = team1()

team1_attempt = Label(text = team1.score).pack()
team1_button = Button(text="Goal!", command = team1.goal).pack()
```

Hope someone can help! New to python.

Comment: your indentation is incorrect, making it impossible to know what your real code is like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two problems with your code.

First problem:

```
team1_attempt = Label(text = team1.score).pack()
```

This sets `team1_attempt` to `None`, because `pack(0` returns `None`. If you want to save a reference to a widget so you can interact with it later you must do widget creation and widget layout in two steps.

Second problem:

```
team1_attempt.set(text = self.score)
```

To change an attribute of a widget, use the `configure` method. I don't know what documentation you read that says  to call `set` on a label widget, but that documentation is wrong.  Use `configure`, like so:

```
test1_attempt.configure(text=self.score)
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using a label, try using an Entry widget that inserts the score into the Entry widget. For example:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.goalButton = Button(master,
                                 text = "goal!",
                                 command = self.goalUpdate)
        self.goalButton.pack() 
        self.goalDisplay = Entry(master,
                                 width = 2)
        self.goalDisplay.pack()
        self.score = 0
    def goalUpdate(self):
          self.goalDisplay.delete(1.0, END) # Deletes whatever is in the score display
          score = str(self.score)
          self.goalDisplay.insert(0, score) # Inserts the value of the score variable
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply!

I am not sure where to input this code to test it out. When I throw it straight in nothing shows up when I run it.

Comment: how is an entry widget better than a label to show static information? Also, you are inconsistent with your text widget indices -- the first index is always the string `"1.0"`, but you used a float of `1.0` when calling `delete` and an int of `0` when calling `insert`.

Comment: When I used the Entry and text widgets, that is what worked for me.